# Conservar informacion entre clases usando observableList en javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

estoy trasteando con javafx con un programa que crea un curso al cual luego se le puede añadir modulos y a esos modulos los alumnos matriculados. Mi problema es el siguiente: Creo los cursos sin problemas, cargo el siguiente controller (modulos) y ahí creo un nuevo modulo, el cual al pulsar modificar se abre la ventana donde añado los alumnos, el problema es que al cerrar la ventana alumnos o modulos pierdo la información. Creo que el problema está en los initAttributtes.

Primera ventana donde se añaden los cursos.

```
public class VentPrinController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button anadircurso;

    @FXML
    private Button modifcurso;

    @FXML
    private Button elimcurso;

    private ObservableList<Curso> cursos;
   
    private ObservableList <String> listacursos;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> combox;

    @FXML
    private MenuButton menuJson;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem AbrirJson;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem guardarJson;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    listacursos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();  
    cursos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    combox.setPromptText("Seleccione o agregue un curso");

    }

    @FXML
    private void combox(ActionEvent event) {

    }

   @FXML
    private void anadircurso(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
 
    
        
    String nomcurs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca un curso", "Entrada", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    Curso nuevocurso = new Curso(nomcurs);
    
            if (!cursos.contains(nuevocurso) && !nuevocurso.getNombreCurso().isEmpty()) {  
        
            cursos.add(nuevocurso);
            listacursos.add(nomcurs);
            combox.setItems(listacursos);
          

          
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("ALERTA");
            alert.setContentText("REGISTRO EXISTENTE, POR FAVOR INTRODUZCA "
                    + "UN CURSO VALIDO.");
                    
            alert.showAndWait();
        } 

        /* FXMLLoader loader = 
           new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("VentanaAnadirCurso.fxml"));
           //Cargo la ventana
           Parent root = loader.load();
            
           // Cojo el controlador
           VentanaAnadirCursoController controlador = loader.getController();
           controlador.initAttributtes(cursos,);
           // Creo el Scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.showAndWait(); */
    }

    @FXML
    private void modificarcurso(ActionEvent event) {

        
      /*  String seleccion = this.combox.getValue(); 
        
        String nomcurs2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca el "
                   + "curso a modificar", "Entrada", 
                   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
 
         if (!cursos.contains(nomcurs2)){
            cursos.remove(seleccion);
            cursos.add(nomcurs2);
            combox.setItems(cursos); 
        
        }*/
      String seleccion = this.combox.getValue(); 
      
       if(seleccion ==null){

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText("Debes seleccionar un curso válido");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
        else{
      
            try {

            // Cargo la vista
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("VentanaModulos.fxml"));

            // Cargo la ventana
            Parent root = loader.load();

            // Cojo el controlador
            VentanaModulosController controlador = loader.getController();
            controlador.initAttributtes(cursos,seleccion);

            // Creo el Scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.showAndWait();


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText(ex.getMessage());
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
           
    }
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void eliminarcurso(ActionEvent event) {

    String seleccion = this.combox.getValue(); 
    
    if (listacursos.contains(seleccion)){
    listacursos.remove(seleccion);
    combox.setItems(listacursos);
    
    for(int i= 0; i<cursos.size();i++) {
       
        if (cursos.get(i).getNombreCurso()==seleccion){
        cursos.remove(i);
    
 }
    
    }


}
```

Ventana segunda donde se añaden los módulos sobre el curso anterior.

```
public class VentanaModulosController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button modmod;
    @FXML
    private Button elimmod;
    @FXML
    private Button anadmod;
    
    private ObservableList<Modulos> modulos;
    private ObservableList<Curso> cursos;
    private ObservableList<String> listamodulos;
    private String nomcurs;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> combox2;
    
    private Curso curso;
   

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    modulos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    listamodulos =FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
    combox2.setPromptText("Seleccione o agregue un módulo");
    
    }    
    
        public void initAttributtes(ObservableList<Modulos> modulos,Curso curso,ObservableList<String>listamodulos) {
        this.modulos = modulos;  
        this.curso=curso;
        this.listamodulos=listamodulos;
       
        }
        
        public void initAttributtes(ObservableList<Curso>cursos,String seleccion) {
        this.cursos=cursos;
        this.nomcurs=nomcurs;
        
    }

    @FXML
    private void anadirmodulo(ActionEvent event) {
        
        
           String nombmod = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca un "
                   + "curso", "Entrada", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            Modulos nuevomod = new Modulos(nombmod);
            
           if (!modulos.contains(nuevomod) && !nuevomod.getNombreModulo().isEmpty()) {  
        
            modulos.add(nuevomod);
            listamodulos.add(nombmod);
            combox2.setItems(listamodulos);
          
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("ALERTA");
            alert.setContentText("REGISTRO EXISTENTE, POR FAVOR INTRODUZCA "
                    + "UN CURSO VALIDO.");
                    
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
        
    }
    

    @FXML
    private void modificarmodulo(ActionEvent event) {
        
     String seleccionMod = this.combox2.getValue(); 
      
       if(seleccionMod ==null){

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText("Debes seleccionar módulo válido");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
        else{
      
            try {

            // Cargo la vista
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("VentanaAlumnos.fxml"));

            // Cargo la ventana
            Parent root = loader.load();

            // Cojo el controlador
            VentanaAlumnosController controlador = loader.getController();
            controlador.initAttributtes(modulos,seleccionMod);

            // Creo el Scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.showAndWait();


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText(ex.getMessage());
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
           
    }
    }

    @FXML
    private void eliminarmodulo(ActionEvent event) {
   
     String seleccion = this.combox2.getValue(); 
    
    if (listamodulos.contains(seleccion)){
    listamodulos.remove(seleccion);
    combox2.setItems(listamodulos);
    
    for(int i= 0; i<modulos.size();i++) {
       
        if (modulos.get(i).getNombreModulo()==seleccion){
        modulos.remove(i);
    
 }
    
    }
    
    }
    }
```

Y por último la ventana de los alumnos donde se añaden los dichos alumnos sobre la ventana modulos:

```
public class VentanaAnadirAlumnoController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtnombre;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtapellidos;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtedad;
    @FXML
    private Button btnguardar;
    @FXML
    private Button btnsalir;

    private Persona persona;

    private ObservableList<Persona> personas;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    public void initAttributtes(ObservableList<Persona> personas) {
        this.personas = personas;
    }

    public void initAttributtes(ObservableList<Persona> personas, Persona p) {
        this.personas = personas;
        this.persona = p;
        // cargo los datos de la persona
        this.txtnombre.setText(p.getNombre());
        this.txtapellidos.setText(p.getApellidos());
        this.txtedad.setText(p.getEdad() + "");
    }

    @FXML
    private void guardar(ActionEvent event) {
        // Cojo los datos
        String nombre = this.txtnombre.getText();
        String apellidos = this.txtapellidos.getText();
        int edad = Integer.parseInt(this.txtedad.getText());

        // Creo la persona
        Persona p = new Persona(nombre, apellidos, edad);

        // Compruebo si la persona existe
        if (!personas.contains(p)) {

            // Modificar
            if (this.persona != null) {

                // Modifico el objeto
                this.persona.setNombre(nombre);
                this.persona.setApellidos(apellidos);
                this.persona.setEdad(edad);

                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setTitle("Informacion");
                alert.setContentText("Se ha modificado correctamente");
                alert.showAndWait();

            } else {
                // insertando

                this.persona = p;
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setTitle("Informacion");
                alert.setContentText("Se ha añadido correctamente");
                alert.showAndWait();

            }

            // Cerrar la ventana
            Stage stage = (Stage) this.btnguardar.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText("La persona ya existe");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void salir(ActionEvent event) {
        this.persona = null;
        // Cerrar la ventana
        Stage stage = (Stage) this.btnguardar.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();

    }

    public Persona getPersona() {
        return persona;
    }

  
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Los datos generados en los diferentes controladores los estás almacenando en variables de instancia, no en un medio persistente como podría ser una base de datos o un fichero.

Podrías solucionarlo a través del [patrón Singleton](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/ejemplo-de-java-singleton-patrones-classloaders/). No sé si es la mejor solución, pero creo que sí que podría servirte para "almacenar" esos datos que quieres que sean accesibles desde los diferentes controladores.

Por ejemplo, podrías añadir una clase tal que así:

```java
public class Instituto {
    
    private static final Instituto miInstituto;
    private static ObservableList<Curso> cursos;
    private static ObservableList<Modulo> modulos;
    private static ObservableList<Persona> personas;
    
    public static Instituto getInstituto() {
        if (instituto == null) {
            miInstituto = new Instituto();
        }
        return miInstituto;
    }
    
    public ObservableList<Curso> getCursos() {
        return cursos;
    }
    
    public void setCursos(ObservableList<Curso> cursos) {
        this.cursos = cursos;
    }
    
    public ObservableList<Modulo> getModulos() {
        return modulos;
    }
    
    public void setModulos(ObservableList<Modulo> modulos) {
        this.modulos = modulos;
    }
    
    public ObservableList<Persona> getPersonas() {
        return personas;
    }
    
    public void setPersonas(ObservableList<Persona> personas) {
        this.personas = personas;
    }
}
```

Para recuperar los datos o para almacenar las nuevas listas simplemente deberías llamar a los métodos get y/o set de la clase `Instituto`.

Referencias a lo comentado hasta ahora:

1. [Cannot force JavaFX TableView to refresh from another Window/Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430837/cannot-force-javafx-tableview-to-refresh-from-another-window-controller)
2. [How to get data in one Java FXML Controller from another FXML Controller (these controllers are not nested controllers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883563/how-to-get-data-in-one-java-fxml-controller-from-another-fxml-controller-these)
3. [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

---

Otras cuestiones que no tienen que ver con la pregunta que has propuesto.

Una pregunta... **¿Cuál es el motivo para que crees dos listas que contienen lo "mismo"?**

Entiendo que lo haces para que la lista de tipo String almacene el nombre del módulo para que se viesualice correctamente en el combobox. Una forma más simple de hacerlo es sobreescribiendo en las clases correspondientes el método `toString()`. Retornas el texto formateado tal y como quieres que se muestre en el combobox.

Para terminar, algunas cuestiones respecto al código que has pegado en tu consulta.

Por un lado, en el segundo método de `initAttributes` del controlador **VentanaModulosController** debes cambiar:

```java
public void initAttributtes(ObservableList<Curso>cursos,String seleccion) {
        this.cursos=cursos;
        this.nomcurs=nomcurs;
```

por:

```java
 public void initAttributtes(ObservableList<Curso>cursos,String seleccion) {
        this.cursos=cursos;
        this.nomcurs=seleccion;
```

Por otro lado, el segundo método de `initAttributes` del controlador **VentanaAnadirAlumnoController** lo has implementado de tal manera que los argumentos que espera son una lista de personas y una persona, en cambio a la hora de llamar al método desde el controlador **VentanaModulosController** le estás pasando una lista de módulos y un módulo como argumentos.